# How can I combine format and print in prolog?

Tags: prolog

How can I combine format and print in prolog?

Basically, I pretend to print a message like "Element 5 occurs 3 times" in prolog. Number 5 and 3 depends of the execution.

In Python, it would be like:

```
print("Element %d occurs %d times" % (element, occurrences))
```

For example, in a small example like:

```
count_occur(X, [], N) :- write("Element ??X occurs ??N times.").
```

Comment: I know it is generally frowned upon to suggest it, but in this case reading the documentation will almost certainly help.

Comment: I did that at first, but it is my first time developing in prolog and I still do not quite understand many things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `format/2` like:

```
count_occur(X, [], N) :-  format('Element ~d occurs ~d times ~n',[X, N]).
```

Example:

```
?- count_occur(2,[],3).
Element 2 occurs 3 times
true.
```